# Cannot create an instance of class ViewModel with constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I'm trying to use the viewmodel in my activity but my app crashes the error "Cannot create an instance of class" from the viewmodel. The ViewModel is like this:

```
class MyViewModel@Inject constructor(val application: Application) : ViewModel() {
   //...
}
```

In my activity, I have this:

```
class Activity: BaseActivity(){
       val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()

       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       }
}
```

If I delete the constructor, my app works but I need to get packageName, so I need context or application.

Why I'm getting this error? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AndroidViewModel

```
class MyViewModel@Inject constructor(val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using Dagger-hilt may b you can't add @HiltViewModel. also check in your activity whether this tag (@AndroidEntryPoint) is added or not.